# ASP.NET: Dealing with Master Pages. Administrative Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, admin, visibility

I'm trying to understand how this works. My idea is to make administrable project using Master Pages like this:

`Admin Head Section`
`User Head Section`
`-----------------`
`Admin Content PlaceHolder`
`User Content PlaceHolder`

1) Should it be done using single Master Page or 2 (Admin.Master + Main.Master) ?
2) Is it possible to hide Admin section if user is not authenticated in Code Behind by DB?

Whole idea is to write minimum amount of code in target .aspx pages (2 directories: 1 for admin tasks, 1 for plain user actions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [Nested Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx) will help you a lot or at least it would be right way to deal with this design.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built in FormsAuthentication and AspNetSqlMembershipProvider, then I would go with one master page, and make use of the `LoginView` control. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295194.aspx

This way you can customise what users see if they are logged in, and then what roles they are subscribed to.

You can then have all your admin pages within a folder and set your access to this folder only allowed for users who are in an admin role. That way if someone navigates to a page within this folder, they will automatically be redirected away from it.